# Database update in laravel using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, database, laravel, laravel-6

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.webslesson.info/2018/02/update-or-edit-mysql-data-in-laravel-using-ajax-with-datatables.html) to update or edit database table in Laravel. I have implemented the insertion section as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#form_output').html('');
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('ajax_data_manage.fetchdata')}}",
                method:'get',
                data:{id:id},
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#player_name').val(data.player_name);
                    $('#player_country').val(data.player_country);
                    $('#player_age').val(data.player_age);

                    $('#player_id').val(id);
                    $('#playerModal').modal('show');
                    $('#action').val('Edit');
                    $('.modal-title').text('Edit Data');
                    $('#button_action').val('update');
                }
            })
        });
```

**in controller file**:

```
function fetchdata(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('id');
    $player = Player::find($id);
    $output = array(
        'player_name'    =>  $player->player_name,
        'player_country' =>  $player->player_country,
        'player_age'     =>  $player->player_age
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

I think the error is in fetching the data. My Player table in the database has three columns (name, country, age) and the id and name of text-box in the form group:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Player Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="player_name" id="player_name" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Player Country</label>
                        <input type="text" name="player_country" id="player_country" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Player Age</label>
                        <input type="text" name="player_age" id="player_age" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
```

when I click the edit button, nothing is happen. I have also edited the `web.php` file

```
Route::get('ajaxdatamanage','AdminController@index')->name('ajax_data_manage');
Route::get('ajaxdatamanage/getdata', 'AdminController@getdata')->name('ajax_data_manage.getdata');
Route::post('ajaxdatamanage/postdata', 'AdminController@postdata')->name('ajax_data_manage.postdata');

Route::get('ajaxdatamanage/fetchdata', 'AdminController@fetchdata')->name('ajax_data_manage.fetchdata')
```

Comment: 1. check data is coming from controller by putting console.log (data) in success function

Answer (score 1):

You will get full demo for this and it will help full for you.

https://github.com/PriyankPanchal/AJAX-CRUD-Laravel

Please clone project from using above link and after clone fire some command as below.

1) composer update
2) Set Up env file and set database details in .env file.
3) php artisan migrate

Hope this demo project will help you.
Thanks
PHPanchal

Answer (score 0):

```
function fetchdata(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('id');
    $player = Player::find($id);
    $output = array(
        'player_name'    =>  $player->player_name,
        'player_country' =>  $player->player_country,
        'player_age'     =>  $player->player_age
    );
    // try this 
    $update = Player::where('id',$id)->update($output);
    // or 
    $player->player_name;
    $player->player_country;
    $player->player_age;
    $player->save();
    echo json_encode($player);
}
```

Comment: Explaining why/how your code solves the issue posted by OP would be more helpful to future visitors.